# error in reading file from com port using c++

Tags: c++, serial-port, readfile

```
            cout<<"getting in issue read operation"<<endl;
    ReadFile(hSerial, readbuff, dwBytesRead, &dwBytesRead, NULL);
    cout<<"error: "<<GetLastError()<<endl;
    if (!ReadFile(hSerial, readbuff, dwBytesRead, &dwBytesRead, NULL))
    {
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
            cout << "Error in communications; report it.";
        else
            fWaitingOnRead = TRUE;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "no waiting\n";
        cout << "no. of bytes read: " <<dwBytesRead << endl;
        cout<<"read buff: ";
        for (DWORD i = 0; i < sizeof(writebuff); i++)
        {
            cout<< readbuff[i];`enter code here`
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
```

i cant understand whats going wrong coz each tym i have 0 bytes read..... 
help me plzzz.....

Comment: Just a quick note: Do **not** check `GetLastError` if a function succeeds, the value is only valid if a function have failed.

Comment: Why does your code call `ReadFile` twice? It's very hard to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you showed how you opened and initialized the serial port, as well as knowing the settings on the other computer. Have you tried using a terminal emulator to see that the other end is actually sending anything? Or a terminal emulator on the other end and try to send dummy data?

Comment: Also, COM ports: cables, tx/rx pins, hardware flow-control, baud rates etc etc.  More simply - does the connection work anyway?

Comment: i m trying to write on a com port using write buff and then reading it  in readbuff...

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I would say that is the problem here, as the first `ReadFile` reads the data, and the second have no data to read.

Comment: You have two ports, pins 2 & 3 linked on one port, or controller in loopback?

Comment: hSerial = CreateFile("\\\\.\\COM25",
                      GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                      NULL,
                      NULL,
                      OPEN_EXISTING,
                      FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                      NULL);

Comment: @DavidSchwartz .... thanx but its still nt working

Comment: @new: That's not a very detailed problems description. What are you expecting it to do? How are you expecting it to do it? What's actually happening? (How is your hardware setup? Why do you expect to be able to read the data back? Is something returning it to you?)

Comment: 1.open a com port
2. write an AT command
3. receiving back the response...
this is all i m trying to do... write command responds successful bt while reading i just get 0 read... and a blank buffer..
 i hv connected a dongle to my lptp

Comment: @new Did you set the correct baud rate? Did you check `GetLastError` like the documentation for `ReadFile` says? Are you sure the dongle is supposed to accept `AT` commands? (Not all do. Test with a terminal program.)

Comment: got it all correctd..... thanku for help... :) @DavidSchwartz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must check the value returned by ReadFile. Call GetLastError only if ReadFile returns zero.

ReadFile parameter 3 should be the size of your buffer. Parameter 4 should be a separate variable that will receive the number of bytes actually read.

Since you are passing NULL for Parameter 5 you will not get overlapped operation, so ReadFile will never return ERROR_IO_PENDING.

You may have more success if you use a proven library for serial port operations, such as this one:

http://www.naughter.com/serialport.html

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVN... got it correctd.... nw my progrm is working fine...
thanku for help.... :) :) :)